# Making a table of solutions from NSolve or Solve

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, code-request, approximation, code-generation

How can I generate a table of solutions to an equation such as this:

> Solve[{a^m+b==c,b-m==a+Sqrt[n]},{a,b}]

for some given values for $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table[
     Solve[{a^m + b == c, b - m == a + Sqrt[n]}, {a, b}],
 {n, 1, 3}, {m, 1, 4}]
```